# Understanding ようでなければ

Tags: grammar

> が、すぐに理解する。恐ろしきは天使の力。しかしそれくらいできる**ようでなければ**、ウェストコットが手にする意味がない。

The guy called ウェストコット wanted to own the power of the 天使.
How is the bold part different from just “できなければ”? I know ようだ can mean “as if” or “like” but I have a hard time fitting the meaning in the context.

Comment: [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9345/omitting-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%a0-at-the-end-of-a-sentence) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/67881/ambiguity-of-x%e3%81%ae%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%a0) might help you understand ようだ

Comment: Related?: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30194/how-to-use-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8d%e3%82%83-correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ようだ before a conditional expression can be just an euphemism. 明鏡国語辞典 has the following definition:

> 《「…ようなら」「…ようだったら」などの形で》仮定を婉曲に示す。「助けがいるようなら連絡してくれ」「この薬で治らないようだったら病院へ行く」

In the example above, 助けがいるようなら and 助けがいるなら are almost the same ("If you need help"), but the former sounds a little more reserved, as if the speaker thinks it's unlikely the listener will need help. This depends on the context but you usually do not have to use *seem*, *appear* or *look* to translate this type of よう.

Comment: I wonder if you are using 'euphemism' correctly here:  https://www.dictionary.com/browse/euphemism ? If that definition matches your understanding could you say a little more about how to use よう in this way please?

Comment: @user3856370 The version with ような sounds more "indirect" to me, like *would* as in *I would say*. It may be like saying *in case* instead of *if*, but I may be wrong...The difference is not big.